# System.out.print(Math.pow( 9 , 1/3)) ; Result = 1.0 ; Why?

Tags: java, pow

I am new to JAVA, and I am trying to learn the language; please excuse me if I am being silly.

So I was testing out Math.Pow( ) and came across that when I use a division function in the second argument my result is always '1.0', no matter what the values I put in both the arguments. Help?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double a= 27 , b = 1/3 ;
    System.out.println(Math.pow(a,b));
}
```

run:
  1.0
  BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1/3` is zero. `Math.pow(a,0)` is `1` for all `a != 0`, in particular for `a = 27`.

The `1/3` division is performed between two integers using integer division, before the result is converted to a `double`. You can get the result you are looking for by ensuring that the number is done using double division, e.g. `1.0/3`.

Answer (score 2):

1/3 is integer division, which would evaluate to 0 as an integer first before setting it equal to b. That would make b = 0, so Math.pow(27, 0) = 1.

Change that to 1.0/3.0, then it becomes 0.3333. This is what you want.